# Java 8 stream string manipulation and comparison

Tags: java, java-8

In Java 8, can I use streams to manipulate, filter and compare string? I know how to do in java 5 but stuck with Java 8 api using Streams. Please assist with Java 8

Let us assume I have two Java objects (Request and Response) as below

```
public class Request {
   
     List<String> requestIds;

     requestIds = new ArralyList();
     requestIds.add("xyz:one/first/same");
     requestIds.add("zzz:five/match/same");
     requestIds.add("xyz:different/second/different");
 }

public class Response {
     List<Item> responseIds;
     responseIds = new ArralyList();
     Item one = new Item("xyz:ten/first/same");
     Item two = new Item("zzz:three/match/same");
     Item three = new Item("xyz:one/third/second");
     responseIds.add(one);
     responseIds.add(two);
     responseIds.add(three);
 }
public class Item {
  String id;
}
```

I need to compare the request and response list objects as below

From request List I need extract indexOf first "/" for each list entry (for example "/first/same") and compare this string with Response list to see which contains or not. If contains add it to result list.

Java 5 Impl:

```
   List result = new ArrayList();
   for(String requestString:requestIds){
   String extractedRequestString = requestString.subString(requestString.indexOf("/"));
   for(int i=0;i<responseIds.length;i++) {
      String responseString = responseIds.get(i).getId();
      if (responseString.equals(extractedRequestString)) {
          // If condition true, Adding request I'd value to result ArrayList
              result.add(requestString);
        }
   }
 }
```

Java 8:
I am trying like,

```
 List resultList = reponseIds.parallelStream.filter()
```

Expected result:

```
Result -  ["xyz:one/first/same"
          "zzz:five/match/same"]
```

Comment: You mean to compare exact match or just content after `/`?

Comment: You need to write an appropriate [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) for the [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) method. Do you not know how to write the `Predicate` method [test](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html#test-T-)? Also, do you really require a parallel stream?

Comment: Here `String responseString = responseIds.get(i);` is not going to return you String, It's going to return `Item` Object

Comment: How you got `yyy:one/first/same` in Result, but you are adding `requestString`, and there is no such item in it.?

Comment: @Navath. Need to compare the string content after first "/"

Comment: @Navath, updated the typo error

Comment: @Abra, adding parallel stream for quick processing

Comment: Parallel stream is not always quicker than sequential stream. Have you profiled the two to verify that using a parallel stream performs quicker processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Your code looks broken to me. Based on your "Java 5 Impl" logic I will assume `responseIds` should be:...</s>

Update: According to your comment both the request and response need to `id.substring(id.indexOf("/"));`

Given that assumption you could do:

```java
    // Transforming ids here to avoid doing it for each element in requestIds
    List<String> stringResponseIds = responseIds.stream()
      .map(item -> item.id.substring(item.id.indexOf("/")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> result = requestIds.stream().filter(id -> {
      // extracting here instead of using `map` to avoid loosing the complete string
      String extractedRequestString = id.substring(id.indexOf("/"));
      // A simple contains now that responses are Strings.
      return stringResponseIds.contains(extractedRequestString);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Runnable example: https://replit.com/@lrn2prgrm/StreamStringMatching#Main.java

Comment: Response Item will have values in the format of "xyz:one/first/same". And request also will have values in the format of "xyz:one/first/same". I need to compare the content is same/match after first "/" indexof. In my above example, first 2 inputs matching between request and response.

Comment: In my sample request, after indexOf("/")  the content is /first/same which will be compared with response list after doing indexof ("/")

Comment: It has been updated now.

Comment: Thanks Corlaez. Is it good idea to use substring to extract string. Will it be causing any perf impact? Any other lib can be used?

Comment: If performance really matters to you I would use for loops and avoid streams. However, do not optimize prematurely. Do you have specific goals in mind? If so measure the performance and only refactor if your goals aren't met.